# Bash script equivalent in windows to run pip and python commands?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, exe

I have a python code which I need to send it to a client who will run it windows. 
The python code works on a few imported modules mentioned in `requirements.txt`:

```
requests==2.11.1
xlwt==1.1.2
beautifulsoup4==4.5.1
```

If I have to execute the code in windows, I’ll have manually ask the client to download these above modules before running the script. 
I have created a bash script ( for linux), which is such:

```
sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
echo "Requirements met"
python ./isb.py
```

What is the bash script equivalent in windows? I want to client to only execute 1 file which executes other remaining files.

Can an executable be made for a task like this? 
The code and other files are [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0byAC8kZZPhYklnRVEzN245WFk?usp=sharing) if need be.

Comment: You can put those same cormands in a `.bat` file. There is no direct equivalent to `sudo`, though. Maybe you'll want to use a virtual environment, in which case no `sudo` is necessary or useful, anyway.

Comment: The `ShellExecuteEx` "runas" verb (e.g. in PowerShell: `saps pip -args 'install -r requirements.txt' -verb runas`) is approximately like gksudo, but the command runs in a new console, since Windows wants the console host (conhost.exe) to use the same security context as its clients (cmd.exe, python.exe, etc). It would be frustrating to have error messages and warnings briefly flashed in a new console window. As such, you may simply want a PowerShell script that requires administrator access.

Answer (score 0):

I has similar task in the past. So I just used a tool py2exe which builds a standalone executable and it resolves dependencies at build time. A valid python interpreter will be included to the build. So your client can just execute this standalone exe file by double-click or from cmd shell.

Comment: Does it include the 3rd part module installations?

Comment: Yes, it packs all modules as .pyc as I remember